# Send email with PDF attachment with umlauts üäö and with HTML content in body

Tags: php, email, diacritics

i handcraft a php file and it works. it sends a fpdf as attachment. but now, how to use umlauts in sender, subject and text and how use html-content instead of only unformatted text in mail body?

here is my code:

```
<?php

require('fpdf/fpdf.php');

$pdf = new FPDF('P','mm','A4');

$pdf->AddPage();

$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);

$pdf->Cell(40,10, "this is a pdf example");


$to = "to@blah.com";
$from = "blah <blah@blah.de>";
$subject = "Test";

// a random hash will be necessary to send mixed content

$separator = md5(time());

// carriage return type (we use a PHP end of line constant)

$eol = PHP_EOL;

// attachment name
$filename = "Test.pdf";

// encode data (puts attachment in proper format)

$pdfdoc = $pdf->Output("", "S");
$attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode($pdfdoc));

// main header
$headers  = "From: ".$from.$eol;
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0".$eol;
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; charset=utf-8; boundary=\"".$separator."\"";

// no more headers after this, we start the body! //

$body = "--".$separator.$eol;
$body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit".$eol.$eol;
$body .= "hallo, test".$eol;

// attachment

$body .= "--".$separator.$eol;
 $body .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$filename."\"".$eol;
$body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64".$eol;
$body .= "Content-Disposition: attachment".$eol.$eol;
$body .= $attachment.$eol;
$body .= "--".$separator."--";

// send message


mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);

//name of pdf file

$pdf_file = "test.pdf";

// additional output pdf

$pdf->Output('I', $pdf_file);

?>
```

can you help me? im simply to stupid.... i have tried many things with utf etc. but it doesnt work...

Comment: This question has nothing to do with FPDF. It's just a basic question about emails. You should use an emailing library.

Comment: hi, fpdf is not the problem. my problem is how to send the fpdf as attachment with umlauts and html body mail text

Answer (score 0):

you should use PHPMailer - Mailing library

https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

it is easy to handle & it never fails to send an email

Comment: Hi, i know phpmailer. I solved my problem in the meantime